# MySQL: How to ignore /etc/mysql/my.cnf for mysqld --initialize

Tags: mysql

I compile a 5.7 MySQL database from source into a custom directory and use `mysqld --initialize` to initialize the database.

This works fine as long as there is no MySQL installed on the main system, or when I use `mv /etc/mysql/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf_backup` to get rid of the system-wide file, but of course that is a terrible workaround that breaks the system-wide mysql installation.

If a `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` is present, the initialization fails obviously as the paths are all wrong.

`mysqld --initialize` always seems to prefer `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and ignores any file I specify on the command line with `--defaults-file`. It does however use single parameters that are specified on the command line (so it may work if I translate my complete my.cnf file into command line arguments, but that again is not a good solution and creates other problems)

Of course the whole point why I build from source into a custom directory is because I want it independent from any things that are installed on the main system.

Is there a way to let `mysqld --initialize` ignore `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`?

Comment: IIRC the defaults-file option has to be specified first or it will be ignored. The manual just says that it has to be first, though. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-directory-initialization-mysqld.html

Comment: Wow, that was actually the problem - I would have never thought of that... - Please create an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Glad I could help. Answer is created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-directory-initialization-mysqld.html) mentions that the `--defaults-file` option has to be specified first, if you want to use it.
Otherwise the option is ignored.